# New JS Library, how to improve it?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to improve on a small library I'm starting to write:

```
var syn=(function(){
    var container = {};
        return function(variable){
            return{
                val: container[variable],
                is: function(value){
                    container[variable] = value;
                }
            };
        };
    })();
```

Currently it's capable of storing snippets of information using the syntax `syn("a").is(42);` and returning the value by using `syn("a").val`.

I'd like to be able to do two things with this library:

1. I'd like to be able to create new instances of the syn object, so I could create multiple "synapses". e.g., `var SynapseA = new syn;`
2. I'd like to reduce `syn("a").val` to just `syn("a")` so that if I refer to `syn("a")` without a property or method it returns the equivalent of `syn("a").val`, but I have no idea how this would be done?

Appreciate any help...

Comment: One thing that's odd is you're accessing container at an index, when container is an object. This doesn't make sense to me. Does it actually work?

Comment: `is` sounds like an equality test to me, not like a setter. I really suggest you to rename this. Also, how would you like this to work with the new getter syntax? If `syn("a")` returns the value, it cannot also return an object with an `is` method at the same time.

Comment: `container[variable]` if you notice the brackets, (conventionally speaking, if it works, then I'm not understanding 100% of how objects work in JS), that's an array. Example: `container[1]` you're accessing the object at container at index 1. How you access objects would be more like this `container.objectName`. Doesn't help your question at all, just something I noticed. Looks odd, but if it works then I'm sure there's a valid reason. Just curious to see what it is.

Comment: *"if I refer to `syn("a")` without a property or method it returns the equivalent of `syn("a").val`"*: this is not possible, because the first expression will always need to support the `.val` property so that the second expression will work. Think of `a = syn("a"); console.log(a.val);`: that should work, but then `a` cannot be exactly the value, since it must have the `val` property.

Comment: Building off of @Bergi and trincot, if a user does `syn("a").is(42)`, then does `syn("a").is(1)`, that would throw an error, because the number 42 does not have an `is` method.

Comment: If you'd like people to review your code, please post a question at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `is()` in this case, is a setter function, probably not the best choice of naming convention... Does that clear things up?

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I'm actually asking about how to alter this library so that I can create instances of it as will as reduce a specific method... Would that class as code review?

Comment: @Bergi so `container.objectName` and `container[objectName]` is the same thing?

Comment: @Bergi so `variable` would then have to be a string for the OP to work?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm Not quite right... `container["objectName"]` is the same as `container.objectName`...

Comment: Your original comment was: @Bergi so `container.objectName` and `container[objectName]` is the same thing?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm you simply forgot to encapsulate objectName in quotes b in the second part... ;)

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio yes I forgot I posted a wrong comment above the correct one, you're right.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm In any case, let's delete this off-topic discussion from the comments

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're asking I think:

```
var syn = function() {
    this.container = {};
}

syn.prototype.is = function(index, value){
  this.container[index] = value;
}

syn.prototype.val = function(index){
  return this.container[index];
}
```

I can do the following:

```
var synapseA = new syn();
synapseA.is("a", 42);
console.log(synapseA.val("a"));

var synapseB = new syn();
synapseB.is("a", 30);
console.log(synapseB.val("a"));

synapseB.is("b", 20);
console.log(synapseB.val("b"));
```

And I get 42, 30 and 20 logged out. Is this what you're after?

Comment: Why did you change `container` from the object to an array?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible, because it is in some way contradictory:

> I'd like to reduce `syn("a").val` to just `syn("a")` so that if I refer to `syn("a")` without a property or method it returns the equivalent of `syn("a").val`

Assume this were possible, and the value stored for "a" is 42 as in your example, then both of the following expressions would need to return 42:

```
syn("a")
syn("a").val
```

But if the first returns 42, then the second can't work: 42 does not have a property `val`. If the second works, then the first will necessarily return an object with a `val` property, which obviously is not what 42 is. So this is a contradiction.

In my opinion, the closest you can get to what you want, is relying on the special `valueOf` method, which will kick in when you force coercion to a number (or boolean). However, for this to work, you must assume that the values you store, are indeed numbers.

Here is how it would work:

```js
function Syn() { // constructor, so you can create more than 1 syn object
    var container = {};
    var f = function(variable){
        return {
            valueOf: function() { // special method
                return container[variable];
            },
            val: container[variable],
            assign: function(value){
                container[variable] = value;
            }
        }
    };
    // Only include next line, if you REALLY need the returned
    // object to be considered an instance of Syn:
    Object.setPrototypeOf(f, Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
    return f;
}

var syn = new Syn();
console.log(syn instanceof Syn); // true
syn("a").assign(42);
console.log(syn("a").val); // 42
console.log(+syn("a")); // 42, because `syn("a")` is coerced to number
```

NB: I renamed the method `is` to `assign`, as that seems more meaningful.

Similarly to `valueOf`, you could rely on `toString`, which does a similar thing when you coerce the return value of `syn("a")` to string:

```js
function Syn() { // constructor, so you can create more than 1 syn object
    var container = {};
    var f = function(variable){
        return {
            toString: function() { // special method
                return container[variable];
            },
            val: container[variable],
            assign: function(value){
                container[variable] = value;
            }
        }
    };
    // Only include next line, if you REALLY need the returned
    // object to be considered an instance of Syn:
    Object.setPrototypeOf(f, Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
    return f;
}

var syn = new Syn();
console.log(syn instanceof Syn); // true
syn("a").assign("hello");
console.log(syn("a").val); // "hello"
console.log(''+syn("a")); // "hello", because `syn("a")` is coerced to string
```

Comment: What if the value stored could be anything, not just a number?

Comment: There is just one other variant I know of: `toString` which will always return a string version of the stored value when you coerce it to string, like by adding another (possibly empty) string to it. See addition to my answer. If you are looking to a way to return a data type corresponding to whatever you stored earlier: that is not possible via coercion, which by definition works towards one particular data type. And coercion is the only way to "silently" turn a value into a primitive "equivalent". It is why I started my answer like I did. ;-)